# getElementsByClassName after loop with VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using VueJS and i'm trying to loop on html elements after loop.

First i use worpress API to get categories then posts by categories.

I have exactly 5 categories in my database.

I have no v-if on my code, maybe i can't loop because my DOM is not ready with my v-for ?

I don't understand why i can't loop my elements.

```
<template>
  <div id="tutos">
    <div
      v-for="(tuto, index) in tutos"
      :id="tuto.categorie_slug"
      :key="index"
      class="row"
    >
      <div class="tutos-list"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Tutos",
  data() {
    return {
      tutos: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getCategories: async function () {
      const categories = await this.axios.get("/categories");
      return categories.data;
    },
    getPosts: async function (id) {
      const posts = await this.axios.get("/posts?categories=" + id);
      return posts.data;
    },
  },
  mounted: async function () {
    // Load datas
    await this.getCategories().then((data) => {
      Array.from(data).forEach((categorie) => {
        if (categorie.count > 0) {
          this.getPosts(categorie.id).then((posts) => {
            this.tutos.push({
              categorie_name: categorie.name,
              categorie_slug: categorie.slug,
              posts: posts,
            });
          });
        }
      });
    });

    // Wait For DOM
    await this.$nextTick();

    const tutos_list = document.getElementsByClassName("tutos-list");
    // Log an HTMLCollection with 5 children
    console.log(tutos_list);

    // Loop Nothing
    Array.from(tutos_list).forEach((list) => {
      console.log(list);
    });
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">...</style>
```

**UPDATE SCREEN**

[Devtools and console screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75YL8.png)

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Log the *tutos* in the console. Don't forget to use Vue devtools to check what are the values of *tutos*. https://devtools.vuejs.org/

Comment: I console log _tutos_ just after nextTick and it return a Proxy with my 5 children in [[Target]]. And in my Vue devtools, i see my _tutos_ var with children as well.

Comment: Upload a picture of tutos logged on console or vue devtools.

Comment: Just did it on my post

Comment: Yeah currently my template render well my categories and my posts `{{ categorie_name }}` display my categorie name.

Comment: Does logging `tutos_list` works and returns an array of selected elements?

Comment: Yeah as you can see on my code (javascript part) `tutos_list`return an HTMLCollection but then when i loop on it, it return nothin

Comment: in vue, prefer using refs than calls to document.*, so it's `this.$refs['tutos-list'].forEach()` instead, and you will need to add `ref="tutos-list"` to your divs. If you still want to use the dom directly, i would use `document.querySelectorAll`, it retuns a `NodeList` that has a forEach function, it's easier than a `HTMLCollection`

Comment: And be careful with the console, even if you see it, it does not means it was there when it was executed, because if it's a reference to an object, the console will be updated when the object is updated. If you need to be sure convert to string before logging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part that loads the data is not awaiting the individual calls to `getPosts`, and the promise returned by the `this.getCategories().then()` call is immediately resolved, as there is no explicit `return` statement in its callback that returns a promise. By consequence this part of your code finishes before any entries have been added with `push`. Those `push` calls happen in a `then` callback that will execute later. Your code doesn't do anything with the promises that these inner `this.getPosts(categorie.id).then()` calls return.

You could use `Promise.all` to await all those `getPosts` promises as follows:

```
    // Load datas
    this.tutos.push(...await this.getCategories().then(data =>
      Promise.all(
        [...data].filter(categorie => 
          categorie.count > 0
        ).map(async categorie => ({
          categorie_name: categorie.name,
          categorie_slug: categorie.slug,
          posts: await this.getPosts(categorie.id)
        }))
      )
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works !! I will study your code to understand everything.